# How can I add multipath TCP ability to my nexus 5?

Tags: nexus-5, networking

I want to be able to connect to my wifi and mobile data plan simultaneously, I've heard that this is possible through **MutlipathTCP** , and that the support of this protocol has been built in android OS. How can I add it to my Nexus 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

First you will need a multipath TCP enabled Nexus 5, which means:

- rooted
- with Android 4.4
- with the kernel developed to enable MPTCP (available [here](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/Android))

Then you will need to subscribe as an alpha tester for an app that lets you use WiFi and cellular network at the same time. Note, though, that it is deprecated. You can find all the useful links at the end of the page I linked.

Comment: when will this be built by defaut in constructors phones ?

Comment: Given the fact that MPTCP is currently an experimental standard under developement, I think we will have to wait a lot to see it come with stock ROMs, if it will at all

Comment: just want to point out for those coming here later that MPTCP is _not_ "experimental" or "under development", and it wasn't when the comment above this one was written. it was published in 2013 [as a final RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6824) and it is deployed in production to all iOS devices.